# How to add a new table with EF core

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing database already that was created when I added Identity to the project. Now I want to add more tables to the database and can't figure out how.

I have created a model for it:

```
public class Match
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public int FullTimeScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchStart { get; set; }  
    public int PrizePool { get; set; }
}
```

My context:

```
public class DynamicBettingUserContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public DynamicBettingUserContext(DbContextOptions<DynamicBettingUserContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

What's the next steps?

Comment: Please share your DBContext. What are you trying to do ? Create an instance of an exisiting table in the DB? or create a new table ?

Comment: @sagi I've updated it now. I'm trying to create a new table

Comment: Razor is a view engine for generating the view, and has nothing to so with EF, or databases

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the `Match` table in your `DynamicBettingUserContext` class like below. Then You need to add migration using `Add-Migration <YourMigrationName>` in Package Manager Console and finally, You have to run `Update-Database` command in PMC.

```
public virtual DbSet<Match> Match { get; set; }
```

Comment: And then 'add-migration' and 'update-database' right?

Comment: @aneko5 yes exactly

Comment: @aneko5 also if you need to set up a specific table name or schema name you can add `Table` attribute to your class, for instance, `[Table("table_name", Schema = "schema_name")]`

Comment: What if there are other tables in database and we just want to add a new table? In this case, by running `Update-Database` it will show an error about other existing tables.